# Blazor app taking long to load on windows server

Tags: blazor-server-side, cloudflare

I'm hosting a Blazor server app on a virtual windows server.
But the problem is that the app takes lot of time to load sometimes. I checked the CPU and RAM, everything looks okay. When I try to run the site from the local IIS(on the server) it loads fast. Last week it was loading fast, so the issue is intermittent.

I'm using CloudFlare free plan to host my web app.
I have also noticed that other web apps show the same symptom when this issue starts.

What else can I look for to diagnose this issue?
Is there a tool that I can use to diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Cloudflare. After turning it off the web app became fast again.